# Slope obtained with GDAL has weird lines

Tags: qgis, gdal, slope, mapzen

I am working with this DEM obtained using [terraincache](https://pypi.org/project/terraincache/), it uses mapzen data. The SRC is WGS 84.

[image: DEM File in QGIS]

I ran this GDAL command to get the slope:

`gdaldem slope -s 111120 dem.tif slope.tif` (I had to do scaling because of the SRC)

The resulting image looks fine but it's not smooth, it has weird lines over it, like contour lines.

[image: Slope file on QGIS]

You can download the DEM file here: https://gofile.io/?c=Du7WnM

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Leaving aside the scale (there is a 20% difference between parallel arc and meridian arc lengths at latitude 38 degrees), the slope calculation is correct for the source data. There are nothing to solve (although a reprojection would be convenient). Do you want to do some interpolation between source pixel values?